# Access user in Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rack

I want a certain redirection to happen only for non logged in users, how can I get the `current_user` object on the middleware? I am using `Devise` for authentication.

Answer (score -2):

`current_user` is a property of the controller, you can call `app.controller.current_user` to get the User object.